# MapServer as a CGI in IIS alongside QGIS (WinServer 2008)

Tags: apache, iis, qgis, mapserver

Has anyone got some experience with MapServer as a CGI running on IIS7 (WinServer2008)?

I get the CGI running fine with a MSSQL2008 plugin. This however doesn't allow me to use a BBOX filter. I install QGIS in order to get the OGR tools and can no long access my PROJ_LIB thereafter.

I get thereafter the following error response from any WFS requests to the MapServer CGI module:

*This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.*

Removing my PROJ_LIB CONFIG reference causes following error excpetion:

*msProcessProjection(): Projection library error. Permission denied*

I got around this problem for now by using the default Apache setup for MS4W. However this requires me to a use a proxy in order to use the WFS in an IIS hosted OpenLayers site.

I hope someone else has a few ideas in this regard.

Cheers,
Dennis